# How to load Properties only once in java?

Tags: java, properties

I have loaded property file in java.

```
public String getproperties(String property)
    InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("test.properties").getInputStream();
            Properties testProperties = new Properties();
            testProperties.load(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            return testProperties.getProperty(propertyType);

}
```

Its loaded successfully.The problem is every time property file loaded instead of loading only once.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the Properties object as a field outside the method, initially null, and only create it on first call:

```
private Properties testProperties = null;

public String getproperties(String property)
    if (testProperties == null) {
        InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("test.properties").getInputStream();
        testProperties = new Properties();
        testProperties.load(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
    }
    return testProperties.getProperty(propertyType);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily cache the properties by doing something like this:

```
class PropertyContainer {
    private static Properties properties;
    public static synchronized Properties getProperties() {
        if (properties != null) { return properties; }
        InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("test.properties").getInputStream();
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Your old `getproperties` method would then be something like this:

```
return PropertyContainer.getProperties().getProperty(propertyType);
```

This of course assumes that you only need one property file.

Comment: it would be good to synchronis the getProperties method in case of multithread app.

Comment: Very true. This has now been changed.

Answer (score -1):

Just create class field Properties properties:)
And save once loaded values there.

Answer (score -1):

I usually wrap this into a private method, storing the object into a private field:

```
private Properties _testProperties;
private Properties properties() {
  if (_testProperties == null) {
        InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("test.properties").getInputStream();
       _testProperties = new Properties();
        inputStream.close();
       _testProperties.load(inputStream);
  }
  return _testProperties ;
}

public String getproperties(String property) {
   return properties().getProperty(property);
}
```